# How to remove Menu Option in Android 4.2.2

Tags: android

My Android App has min sdk and target sdk set to 10, when I run my app on Nexus 4 -Android Version 4.2.2, it shows a menu option button beside the system navigation.

I am not using menu options in my app and I dont want to show the user this useless menu option. How can I remove it ?

I have read about this on http://android-developers.blogspot.com.au/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html but I do not get a concrete solution.

Attached is the image :[image]

I dont want to change the sdk version for my app. Is it possible to remove menu option without changing sdk version?

Comment: set target SDK at least 11 ...

Comment: `minSdk` and `targetSdk` are there to address such situations: you can maintain compatibility with older devices via `minSdk`, while compiling your app with a more recent `targetSdk`. They have not to be the same at all.

Comment: When I am changing target sdk, the app is not launching at all

Comment: changing target SDk to 11 does not help...menu option is still there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply have to modify your `targetSdk` to something above 10. For instance, if you use last SDK you should use `targetSdk=16`

Answer (score 0):

The concrete solution is in the article:

Add theme to your application:

```
<application android:theme="@style/NoActionBar">
```

Then define this theme for pre-Honeycomb in res/values/themes.xml:

```
<resources>
    <style name="NoActionBar" parent="@android:style/Theme">
        <!-- Inherits the default theme for pre-HC (no action bar) -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

and for Honeycomb and later:

```
<resources>
    <style name="NoActionBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Inherits the Holo theme with no action bar; no other styles needed. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: it does not help !! That why I asked this question.

Answer (score -1):

If you set your target SDK version to 11 and below, the android legacy menu button will appear. But just in case you want to keep that target SDK version, you can just delete the method `onCreateOptionsMenu`, this way you won't inflate any options.